# android lint error

Tags: android, proguard

I cannot export nor build my android app because of an error in proguard.cfg.
It says 
Obsolete proguard file; use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames  proguard.cfg

As you can see, I have modified keepclasseswithmembernames with -keepclasseswithmembers. But i am still getting the error

What is the cause of this?

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code and try lint and get no errors.
how about creating new project and copy proguard.cfg from it? the latest ADT seems generate non-obsolete proguard.cfg file.

Comment: thanks, it is true. For some reason, I would still get the error even though I had modified the proguard.cfg file. In order to fix this, I simply removed the error from the 'Problems' view in eclipse. (Right click on the error - Remove). Then, it built fine and exported fine.